# Regex doesn't match as expected

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to write a regex to match the following text:

- **one** of letters `f`, `s` or `t`
- multiple times:

  - **at least one** digit
  - **one** of letters `f`, `s` or `t`

This is the regex I've come up with: `(f|s|t)(\d+(f|s|t))*`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Input: `f20s30t`

Expected matches:

- f
- 20s
- 30t

Actual matches:

- `f`
- `30t`
- `t`

Why is my regex expression wrong?

Edit: I'm using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx) method to split the input.

Comment: By "matches", you meant captures, right? It is not quite clear what you are doing. You may actually just get multiple matches with [`\d*[fst]`](https://regex101.com/r/x67444/1). In .NET, you may grab all the captures by accessing the capture collection related to a certain group. Is it a whole string or part of a longer text?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm using Regex split in C#, but I think that's kind of irrelevant to the question. You can test the regex yourself in regex101.com

Comment: Oh, that is *very* relevant because you should not test the .NET regex patterns at regex101 as it does not support .NET regex. So, is that a whole string or part of a longer text?

Comment: I think you are rather interested in match groups. Are you? You've given only one example - not sufficient when you're asking strangers about a regex. Give a couple of more positive examples as well as negative examples.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I edited the question, thanks

Comment: Yeah. New edit changes a lot.

Comment: BTW where's a huge difference between regex match and split. BTW is your input always going to be in the format similar to  "f20s30t"?

Comment: @Aditya Yes. That's why I wrote the first item list.

Comment: There are ways to multiple match (see my top comment) or split (e.g. split between a letter and a digit, `Regex.Split(s, @"(?<=\p{L})(?=\d)")`), but I suggest that you use your regex (I enhanced it a bit in my answer) with `Regex.Match` since that approach not also extracts the necessary bits, but also validates the input string.

Comment: Better way to `split` that string is using a lookbehind in addition to a lookahead. See here https://ideone.com/j4flOT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using C#, you may *match* a string with a pattern and access the capture collection of each repeated capturing group:

```
var s = "f20s30t";
var m = Regex.Match(s, @"^([fst])(\d+[fst])*$");
if (m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
    foreach (var g in m.Groups[2].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(t => t.Value))
        Console.WriteLine(g);
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that it also *validates* the string, and you won't get results for a string like `TEXT random f20s30t here....`.

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/iut5r9), output

```
f
20s
30t
```

Here is the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%5bfst%5d%29%28%5cd%2b%5bfst%5d%29*%24&i=f20s30t):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of the string
- `([fst])` - Capturing group 1: `f`, `s` or `t`
- `(\d+[fst])*` - 0 or more repetitions (captured into Group 2 with each value saved in the group stack) of:

  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `[fst]` -  `f`, `s` or `t`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

In regex world `(f|s|t)` is equal to `[fst]` but has a few downsides in comparison. So use latter (a character class) in place of former. Using `split` method you could split on this:

```
(?<=[fts])(?=\d+[fts])
```

Above regex matches a position where a character from `[fts]` meets an occurrence of digits following a character from `[fts]`. This `(?<=...)` is a positive look-behind and `(?=...)` constructs a positive look-ahead.

[RegEx live demo](https://regex101.com/r/naMvkk/1)

Code (see demo [here](https://ideone.com/j4flOT)):

```
string input = "f20s30t";
string pattern = @"(?<=[fts])(?=\d+[fts])";

string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
foreach (string match in substrings)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", match);
}
```

Output:

```
f
20s
30t
```

Answer (score 1):

Going by your example code:

```
^([fst]|[0-9]+[fst])$
```

- `^`: start of string
- `[fst]`: one of `f`, `s` or `t`
- `|`: OR
- `[0-9]+`: one or more digits
- `[fst]`: one of `f`, `s` or `t`
- `$`: end of string

In C#:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = "f20s30t";
        string pattern = "([fst]|[0-9]+[fst])";
        string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
        foreach (string match in substrings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", match);
        }
    }
}

//
//f
//
//20s
//
//30t
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tYYYyX)

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kKDESI/1)